# The page tab bar is collapsed when navigated to previous page in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have created two pages in ionic 2 framework. The first page is having navbar and tabbar. The second page is having navbar and toolbar. There is no tabbar. So when I navigate from 1 to 2, it works fine. But, when navigate back from 2 to 1, the page will be collapsed, i.e., there is a space for toolbar. But I don't want the toolbar space in the 1st page. Ho to solve this issue?

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7EvV.png)

Comment: Can you add some code of the page 1 and 3 screenshots of page 1, page 2 and collapsed page 1 navigated back from page 2.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni added screen shots

Comment: You need to share the code on both pages also. Plus, can you check the html+css from inspect element at that space.

Comment: tabsHideOnSubPages: true to the app.module.ts page found it.